# Creating and calling jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have come across plenty of jQuery Plugin Patters (boilerplates) on this website:

[Github jQuery Plugin Patterns](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/patterns/tree/master/patterns)

Nonetheless I was looking even further but I was unable to find anything that would work as I expected. My knowledge for jQuery is quite low, yet I thought I will earn the best if I start creating some small plugins for self... Just for fun and to learn more.

So for example I like this patter:
[Best Options Pattern](https://raw.github.com/jquery-boilerplate/patterns/master/patterns/jquery.best.options.plugin-boilerplate.js)

It looks clean and quite nice to me. However I am not sure why I cannot call the plugin like all other plugins that we can find around... For example backstretch JS or Make it Retina... It is called like this.

```
$.backstretch('path to image');

$.makeItRetina();
```

So I have tried everything that I thought it might work and the only way to call the plugin from that pattern above is following:

```
$(document).pluginName();
```

And I don't want to have it like that... It looks better and simplified if it's just

```
$.pluginName();
```

Anyone to show me the path / way how to do this ? I am really confused.

Comment: Don't you think that calling pluginName() can be simpler than $.pluginName(). What I mean is: "Why do you design it as jquery plugin?" I think this is the reason you difficultly find an example.

Comment: @Plap, the global namespace can be excessively polluted when running a complex web application (especially now that HTML5 specifies that exposing named elements in the global namespace is a good idea). The global jQuery object is usually safer to use, if you're already using the library.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, ah ok, so let's pollute the $ object... What are you saying it's true but here we are talking about a library/plugin, not a commodity variable or function. I avoid placing things in window too, but not for modules and libraries. It's the same way of work of jQuery itself.

Comment: @Plap, my personal stance on this is to only put in `$` library functions that invoke jQuery themselves. Nevertheless, you're right on the long term, `$` will probably reach critical mass a few years from now. Then we can introduce `$._` (or the other way around) and start over.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, Thanks for reply. I agree and in the future (or maybe yet from now) the other way can be an AMD solution like require.js or curl.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extend the jQuery object itself (to call methods on `$`) don't extend `$.fn`, just extend `$`.

When you extend (add methods to) `$.fn`, they are called via `$(selector).method` rather than the `$.method` syntax you are looking for, which requires no special behavior with respect to JavaScript.

Comment: Aham.. Alright Explosion Pills. +1 for this answer and I will check it as correct once it's possible. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var plug = $(document).pluginName();
```

and then call plug.makeItRetina(); or plug.backstretch('path to image');

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Not correct but leaving with comment in case the lesson I learned can be learned by someone else. :)

Comment: Nah, that probably won't work as you intend it to. If the plugin is well-written, `$.fn.pluginName()` will be chainable and return the jQuery object it is called on. So `plug` will contain `$(document)` after the code in your answer runs. It might also contain an arbitrary value if the method was a getter of some sort, but no method will probably return `$.fn` itself.